# how to fix error The value for a v-bind expression cannot be empty Vue Js

Tags: vue.js

Iam tryng in tutorial vue js basic , but i have error on v-bind . i use v-for but having error like this :

```
    <template>
    <div class="todo-list">
        <todo-items 
        v-for="todo in todos" // error on here
        :title="todo.title"  // here
        :description="todo.description"/> // on here
    </div>
</template>




<script>
import TodoItems from '@/components/TodoItems.vue'
export default {
    components:{
        TodoItems
    },
    props:{
        todos:{
            required:true,
            type:Array
        }
    }

}
</script>
```

i dont know what happen on my code , but this tutorial is fine and not get error . but my code is have error on v-for

this error is

> > Errors compiling template:
>
> The value for a v-bind expression cannot be empty. Found in
>   "v-bind:"

can someone tell me about this error ?

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct file? The code you've posted shouldn't be causing that error. Make sure everything is saved and any relevant caches are cleared.

Comment: its cleared and relevant

Comment: The error message suggests you have an attribute of `v-bind:=""` or `v-bind:` or `:=""` or maybe even just `:` by itself. The full error message should include details of the template that failed. I suggest studying that closely to check everything is as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error occurs because the title field of at least one todo object inside the array is undefined or empty.

If you provide the exact structure of the todos array I will update my answer with more details.